# Attached Behaviours or Interaction.Triggers?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm using MVVM to write a WPF application and I'm confused as to what I should use to handle custom routing of EventArgs from the View to my ViewModel.

I have a property called - CurrentIndex on my VM, on my view this is bound to a control;

Value="{Binding CurrentIndex}"

This control has its own set of EventArgs when the value of the control changes (i.e., IndexValueChangedEventArgs).

I am trying to understand how I can trigger this event and have access to the current state of my ViewModel so I can update the viewmodel accordingly.

I have tried to do this with an EventTrigger (which calls the command but it is bound to my VM so I cannot get the custom event args from the control) and created an attached behaviour which gives me access to the custom EventArgs but no relation to my VM.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong within the pattern, all I want to do is get EventArgs from ControlA into something that can interact with my VM and update accordingly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you don't route EventArgs from the View to the ViewModel, you use binding.

Your ViewModel should implement INotifyPropertyChanged.  There are various boilerplate implementations out there, but it's not difficult to do yourself, e.g.

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if(handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private int _currentIndex;
    public int CurrentIndex
    {
        get { return _currentIndex; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _currentIndex)
            {
                _currentIndex = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentIndex");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now your view will be synchronized with changes to your view model using the binding your already have

```
Value="{Binding CurrentIndex}"
```

assuming of course the view's DataContext is set to an instance of your view model.

Comment: Yes, I am doing this and this works well for pushing changes to from my data to the UI.  What I am interested in is handling events from Controls on the UI.  I.e., I have a textbox, I wire up the KeyDown event, I want to access the data in the KeyEventArgs and evaluate that against code running in my ViewModel.  For my command parameters I am primarily passing in the current {Binding} context which is my VM but then I don't have access to the event parameters.

Comment: I see. I don't know how you could do that in MVVM.  Interaction triggers won't help.  I don't know enough about attached behaviours.  Maybe it's time to learn :)